# Can't disable physics in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have two nodes one near another. And I want one node to be on top of another when I tap. I do so like this:

```
SKAction *moveUp=   [SKAction moveByX:0 y:25 duration:0.1];
SKAction *moveDown= [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-25 duration:0.1];
SKAction *playerSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp,moveDown]];
[self.player runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:playerSequence count:1] withKey:@"attack"];
```

And instead I get that one node pushes the other (bots nodes created via editor and both body type is set to none).

I tried adding these to `didMoveToView` on both nodes:

```
node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

I even tried setting velocity to 0 on `Update`. And still no effect.

Comment: have you tried node.physicsBody = nil?

Comment: One couldn't tell unless you show the code where you create those nodes.

Comment: I create nodes with drag and drop, via xcodes editor. (.sks file)

Comment: \*cough\* use swift \*cough\*, ahm what?

Answer (score 1):

Set your bit masks in 
`-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact`
as [shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267600/is-it-posible-to-deactivate-collisions-in-physics-bodies-in-spritekit).

I think you have a timing issue if you set the bit masks in
 `didMoveToView`
because only one of those will be run at a time and both physics bodies will need to mutually agree not contact each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the physics body to nil:

```
node.physicsBody = nil;
```