# How can I make a physics body which you can put another physics body through

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make a `SKPhysicsBody` in swift which allows another physics body to go through it without being affected. I cannot remove the physics body because I need the gravity. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Physics bodies with the same `collisionBitMask` value will "pass-through" each other.".

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21268099/4958802) should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have set both of my `SKSpriteNodes` collition bit mask to 1, but they are unable to pass eachother

Comment: Hi, did you also set the category and contact bit masks?

Comment: No, I did it now. and it is working. Thanks for your help. Also, How can I make a SKPhysicsBody only pass through the bottom to up of the node?

Comment: *"Physics bodies with the same collisionBitMask value will "pass-through" each other."* Not sure I agree with this. If you want `bodyA` to allow `bodyB` to pass through it, then `bodyA`'s `collisionBitMask` must *not* include `bodyB`'s `categorybitMask`. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision/29418/manipulating-contacttest-and-collison-bitmasks-to-enable-disable-specific-contac#t=201705261244093143533.

Comment: @Rishi Setting both collision bit masks to 1 simply means that they will only collide with a body whose categoryBitMask is 1 (or, more correctly, has the 1 bit set on). The `contactTestBitMask` plays no part in collisions and is irrelevant in this discussion.

Comment: @GeorgeHanna *"Physics bodies with the same collisionBitMask value will "pass-through" each other."* This is wrong - bodies with the same collision bit mask simply collide with the same things. This may or may not include each other.

Comment: Yes, please redo this answer,  if the `(p1.collisionBitMask && p2.categoryBitMask) == 0`, then the two objects will not collide.

Comment: @Rishi, you have 2 options, you can add 2 child SKNodes with lines for physics bodies,  or you can check the direction your sprite is contacting your body, and make that determination to activate collision.  If you are doing a breakout style game, I would opt in the first one

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for your help! I think I can check the direction that my player is coming from.